# How to load a dynamic JSP page using ajax?

Tags: html, ajax, jsp

Recently I am doing a `JSP` website to get the information from database. Now I built a function that user can rewrite something on the webpage. But it will go to a new website. I want only to load the changed information in a `HTML` table(the table is worked out with `JSP`). I have tried to load text file with `Ajax` and it worked. But I have no idea how I can do it with dynamic message. I am totally new with `Ajax`.